# Wrong mail attachment name after transition to Java 17

Tags: jakarta-mail, java-17

I used **Java 8** in the project. For mail sending I use `javax.mail` library. Everything worked. I sent a mail with **.xlsx attachment**:

[image]

Now I change to **Java 17** and some problem became: now the attachment looks wrong, like this:

[image]

Now the attachment has name: `=UTF-8B0J7RgtGH0ZHRgiDQv9C+INC30LDQs9GA0YPQt9C60LUg0LfQsNGP0LLQvtC6= =UTF-8BINC40Lcg0JrQkNCfICgwMy4xMS4yMDIzKS54bHN4=`

but, if I save it to the disk and give a normal name and extension (requests_2023_11_17.xlsx), the file opens well.

I have code:

```
for (Attachment attachment : attachments) {
    InternetHeaders headers = new InternetHeaders();
    MimeBodyPart fileAttachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart(headers, attachment.getContent());
    mp.addBodyPart(fileAttachmentPart); // object MimeMultipart

    fileAttachmentPart.attachFile(attachment.getFileName());

    fileAttachmentPart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(attachment.getFileName(), "UTF-8", null));
    fileAttachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new AttachmentDataSource(attachment)));
}
```

I tried to do such things:

1. updated the library `javax.mail` to the latest version
2. added content type for **xlsx**: `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spiedsheetml.sheet"`
3. installed `props.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "false");`

This all did not help. Tell me please, what else can I try to do?

Comment: Are you running the application on Windows? They made [UTF-8 the default encoding in Java 18](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400) and this was different on Windows before that. Maybe this impacted that the whole E-Mail uses UTF-8 in some way and you don't need to use `MimeUtility.encodeText` any more?

Comment: @dan1st , thank you for answer. I use Java 17,  not  Java 18.  Now I tried  not to use ```MimeUtility.encodeText``` but unfortunatly  this does not help. Without this method I get  the attachment:   ```_BGQB __ 703@C7_5 70O2__ 87 ___ (21.11.2023).xlsx```   -> name is wrong, extension is right.

Comment: What does `attachment.getFileName()` return? Did you only change the Java version or did you update dependencies as well? Can you please share a [mcve]?

Comment: @dan1stiscrying, I tried different ways. Unfortunately, nothing is helped. Therefore, finally I simply write the name of attachment using English letters. Name was: ```Отчёт по загрузке заявок.xlsx```. Now, the name is: ```Request report.xlsx```. Of course this helps, because there are never any problems with English letters :-))